Localisation $A_f \cong A_{f^n}$
This seems like a trivial question.
Let $A$ be a ring, and let $f \in A$. Let $A_f$ denote the localisation in $f$. Is it true that
$$
A_f \cong A_{f^n} \,?
$$
I think it's true, given by $A_f \to A_{f^n}$, $a \mapsto a$, $1/f \mapsto f^{n-1}/f^n$. But I have asked others and they said that this is not true because of zero divisors. What do you think?

Immediate consequence of the universal property. And it's a duplicate. Please use site search. Not related to zero divisors indeed.

It is true. If $S,T \subseteq A$ are multiplicative subsets with $S\subseteq T$ with the property that for all $t \in T$ there is some $s \in T$ such that $st \in S$ then the natural homomorphism $S^{-1}A \to T^{-1}A$ is an isomorphism. Here it is $S = {f^{nm} \ : \ m\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ and $T = {f^{m} \ : \ m\in\mathbb{N}_0}$.

To follow up on @MartinBrandenburg's comment, if you invert $f$, you can get $1/f^n$ by $(1/f)^n$, and if you invert $f^n$, you can get $1/f$ by $f^{n-1}/f^n$.
